# How to convert ABS(HASH(...)) from Legacy sql to Standard SQL

Tags: hash, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

In Legacy sql, we can do `SELECT ABS(HASH('12345'))` to get unique hash number of a value.

I am in process of converting legacy sql to standard sql in GBQ, 
so wondering whats the best way to convert above function so that it gives me same value back as legacy sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We won't expose a function that returns the same values as in legacy SQL; it uses an undocumented implementation. The closest equivalent when using standard SQL is [`FARM_FINGERPRINT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#farm_fingerprint), which uses the [open-source FarmHash library](https://github.com/google/farmhash).

For the expression that you provided, you would instead use `ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT('12345'))`.

Comment: ah, ideally there should have been similar functions when you want users to migrate from legacy to standard. Without a similar implementation in Standard sql, I will have to keep a few queries linger in legacy sql and anything new in standard sql. I hope google does not deprecate support for legacy sql anytime soon.

Comment: just for clarification, these hashed ids are kind of permanent in usage and clients are already using it, so those can not change now, thats the reason i can not switch that query to standard sql with different hashing algorithm

Comment: Yes, this is unfortunate. Would it be possible to migrate if `FARM_FINGERPRINT` was also available with legacy SQL?

Comment: Yes, If google provides same hashing function in both types of sqls, then it will be very helpful for a lot of users to migrate easily, going forward.

Comment: I filed [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64689574) on your behalf. You can star it to express interest and get updates. Thanks!

Comment: The function is now available when using legacy SQL. I'm leaving the feature request open until the documentation is done.

Comment: This is not sufficient for us. We have situations where we have saved almost 1 petabyte of data hashed using the Legacy HASH function. We cannot convert our queries to use Standard SQL without re-computing all that HASHed data, plus the coordination of migrating would be a royal pain. Why is it so difficult to have the equivalent HASH implementation in Standard SQL?